# SoapClient and https goes down with error 500 after longtime call response

Tags: php, soap-client

I spent many hours and used many recommendations but without success.
this is my init of SoapClient:

```
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 5000);
$opts = array(
    'ssl'   => array(
        'verify_peer'       => false,
        'verify_peer_name'  => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    ),
    'https' => array(
        'timeout' => 6000,
    ),
    'http'  => array(
        'timeout' => 6000,
    )
);

$options = array(
    'encoding'           => 'UTF-8',
    'verifypeer'         => false,
    'verifyhost'         => false,
    'soap_version'       => SOAP_1_2,
    'trace'              => true,
    'exceptions'         => true,
    //'timeout' => 600, // not work use this: default_socket_timeout
    'connection_timeout' => 500,
    'stream_context'     => stream_context_create($opts),
    'cache_wsdl'         => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    //'compression' => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP | SOAP_COMPRESSION_DEFLATE | 1, //with this: Invalid XML, timeout
    //'keep_alive' => true, //true - timeout, false - timeout
);

$errors = [];

try {
    $this->_client = new \SoapClient("https://{myip}/soap?wsdl", $options);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $errors[] = $e->getMessage();
} catch (\Throwable $e) { // SoapClient can "Fatal Error" before it throws a SoapFault, so by catching both errors and exceptions with Throwable you will have very simple error handling
    $errors[] = $e->getMessage();
}
```

And my problematic long call:

```
try {
    $result = $this->_client->__soapCall('route',
        [$myKey, $someController, $someAction, null]);
} catch (\SoapFault $e) {
    // handle issues returned by the web service
    $errors[] = $e->getMessage();
    return false;
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // handle PHP issues with the request
    $errors[] = $e->getMessage();
    return false;
} catch (\Throwable $e) {
    // handle rest
    $errors[] = $e->getMessage();
}
```

Some responses are ok, but another one which needs more time, they will go down with: "Internal server error" HTTP 500. And timed out it's after approx. 6 - 8 seconds.
This is my server configuration of all timeouts what I found:

```
PHP Version 7.3.14
hard_timeout    2
ic24.api.max_timeout    7
memcache.lock_timeout   15
Read timeout    86400
default_socket_timeout  60  
opcache.force_restart_timeout   180
max_execution_time  30
```

I found this article https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=41631 but I am not sure if it is fixed in PHP >= 7. And also see that many questions are on the internet about this problem.

All problem is on production server Linux Centos. On my local Xampp is all ok. Same configurations. The production server is a little different from Suhosin and mod_security.

I tested by this in htaccess to disable it:

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
  SecRuleEngine Off
  SecFilterInheritance Off
  SecFilterEngine Off
  SecFilterScanPOST Off
  SecRuleRemoveById 300015 3000016 3000017
</IfModule>
```

and

```
php_flag suhosin.simulation On
```

but no luck.

I tried https://gist.github.com/RobThree/2490351, but it doesn't work at all.

I made another test like this:

```
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', -1);
```

And something was changed. It does not wait for a response and without error.

Errors log is enabled but no errors logged.

Production server is php-fpm and is the same as SOAP Server with same IP.

**Update 1:**

Somewhere I read this comment:

> Please note that although you may try to set default_socket_timeout to
>   something over 20s, you may get tricked by the Linux kernel.
>
> The default value of tcp_syn_retries is set to 5, which will
>   effectively timeout any TCP connection after roughly 20s, no matter
>   what limits you set in PHP higher than this.
>
> The value can be altered by root only, like this:
>
> echo 6 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_syn_retries
>
> A value of 6, as above, will give you a timeout up to ~45s.

**Update 2:**

When I call same script over cron, then its OK.

Comment: look on your php config to max_execution_time and memory_limit may be increasing this may help you.   Please look if there are more specific error messages in your php error.log

Comment: @Thomas Updated. Its not about this. I have other scripts which are runnig few minutes. Memory is also defined very high.

Comment: Check your error log for the exact error message.

Comment: Errors log is enabled but no any errors logged.

Comment: @Grumpy As I said. On local dev xampp it works well. Some responses are after few minutes but on develop server is problem. Its about timeout and it looks that after 5 seconds its crash, because timedout. I dont know what else to check or what to set to works.